# How to get SQL / MariaDB INSERT result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, mariadb

one thing I can't really find is to get the new ROW as result after a SQL INSERT.

last_inserted_id() only works if it has an INT ID and if I'm not mistaken it also has to be auto incremented. What I tried now is to create a temporary table and INSERT into the two tables.

It works, only now it is missing the correct ID because it has its own value 0 due to the new table and not like the original ROW. I want to include it in my PHP code and it should also work with different DB tables. Ah and I use MariaDB 10.3 +.

A consideration would be to insert a statement in between "if have last_insert_id then a SELECT INTO ... where id = last_inserted etc. else the snippet below".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_school AS SELECT * FROM school LIMIT 0;
INSERT INTO school ( school_name ) VALUES ( 'blubb' );
INSERT INTO tmp_school ( school_name ) VALUES ( 'blubb' );
SELECT * FROM tmp_school;
```

Comment: What is the "correct ID" then, if not the value from an auto increment column?

Comment: *I can't really find is to get the new ROW as result after a SQL INSERT.* In general this task is not solvable. Provide initial sample data for `school` table as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INT scripts for to reproduce your issue - it is not clear now.

Comment: *last_inserted_id() only works if it has an INT ID and if I'm not mistaken it also has to be auto incremented.* This is correct partially. Autoincrement needed - this is true. INT - no, you need in any integer (TINYINT SIGNED, BIGINT UNSIGNED and so on) or floating-point (FLOAT, DOUBLE) datatype. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01bd138d3d1db3f810499e4af1610694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you can try this :

```sql
INSERT INTO tmp_school (school_name) VALUES ('blubb') RETURNING school_name ;
```

It works the same if you insert several values at once in the regular (not temporary) table:

```sql
INSERT INTO school (school_name) VALUES ('blubb'), ('abc'), ('bcd') RETURNING school_name ;
```

Hope this will help, if your MariaDB server version, supports this statement

Comment: true, since MariaDB 10.5 [DOC](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/)

Answer (score 0):

RETURNING syntax is exactly the same as a SELECT, so you use RETURNING * as well :

```sql
INSERT INTO school (school_name) VALUES ('blubb'), ('abc'), ('bcd') 
RETURNING * ;
```

This query will insert 3 lines into school table and display the same 3 lines

Comment: Right is actually what I need and yes is only available since version MariaDB 10.5.0.
Is it possible to rewrite the solution of RETURNING as SQL query so that it works backwards compatible?

Comment: I am generally surprised that this return option was implemented so differently in MariaDB/MySQL/SQL Server etc. or even very late.

Comment: the only solution I can think about is to create a temporary table same as the original,  then you insert new rows in the temp table and then you insert in the original table and do a select both from the temporary table.